# Energy variance at the vacuum-state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, energy

What is the energy variance at the vacuum-state? Why is the energy variance at the ground-state of the quantum harmonic oscillator zero?

edit: I already (mathematically) know that the energy variance at the ground-state of the quantum harmonic oscillator zero. I am questioning the definition of the QHO since it is not taking into account the vacuum fluctuations. So the variance of the energy of the QHO should be at least equal to the Variance of the fluctuations. And the last is obviously non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

The ground state of the harmonic oscillator is an energy eigenstate, so its energy variance is $0$ as it is for any eigenstate of $H$.  If it were not not this state would not have a definite energy.

More generally of course if $\hat A\vert\psi\rangle=a\vert\psi\rangle$ then $\hat A^2\vert\psi\rangle=a^2\vert\psi\rangle $ so that
$$
\langle\psi\vert \hat A\vert\psi\rangle=a\, ,\qquad
\langle\psi\vert \hat A^2\vert\psi\rangle=a^2
$$
and thus 
$$
(\Delta A_{\vert\psi\rangle})^2
=\langle \psi\vert \hat A^2\vert\psi\rangle-\langle\psi\vert\hat A\vert\psi\rangle^2=a^2-(a)^2=0\, .
$$

Comment: Well, thanks for the try,but that's not the point of the question. I already know that the energy variance at the ground-state of the quantum harmonic oscillator zero and I said it in my question. I am questioning the definition of the QHO since it is not taking into account the vacuum fluctuations. So the variance of the energy of the QHO should be at least equal to the Variance of the fluctuations. And the last is obviously non-zero.

Comment: @AmineBenMhenni  I'm not sure I understand the question v2: do you want something else than $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2\to \hat H=\frac{(\hat p)^2}{2m}+ \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 (\hat x)^2$?

Comment: Well I just want a variance of the energy without discrepancy. And there is seemingly several ways to do that, including your proposition.